# in image editor plus package when i edit a picture its dimensions changes after saving image

Tags: flutter, image, image-editor

how to save default image dimensions(height and width) after editing my image with [Image_editor_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor_plus) , is there any way to not change the image dimensions ?

I want a way to maintain image dimension , if you know other package that has no these such problems and edits image please let me know .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.